# Angular2 Web-Page Not Loading

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, lite-server

My Angular2 web-page is no longer loading. Everything was working fine and then after I saved some code the page would not load.

I've tried to check for errors within my code and fixed them all, but my web-page will still not load.

**courses.component.ts**

````
import {CourseService} from './course.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: ` 
    <h2> Courses </h2>
    {{title}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor = "#course of courses">
        {{course}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    ` ,
    providers: [CourseService]
    // we use the backtick "`" to breakup the template into multiple lines
      // to render the title we used double curly braces also known as "interpolation"
})

export class CoursesComponent {

    // this is a module. It'll be able to be imported to other places

    title: string = "The title of the courses page";

    courses =["Course1", "Course2", "Course3"];

    constructor(courseService: CourseService) {

        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }

}```

--course.service.ts--
```export class CourseService {

    getCourses() : string[] {
        return ["Course1","Course2", "Course3"];
        // this is a service class created to be used with our component
    }
}```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My Hello Angular</h1><courses></courses>',
    directives: [CoursesComponent]
})

**app.component.ts**
```export class AppComponent { 
// the app component is the root of your application
// it controls the entire app/page

}```

Please excuse my formatting is it is not correct. Does anyone know what may be causing my web-page to no longer load?
````

Comment: Why do you have the # before the course on this line: "<li *ngFor = "#course of courses">"? Maybe that is your issue.

Comment: I believe that # sign represents that I would be using that variable repeatedly

Comment: can you setup a [stackblitz example](http://stackblitz.com) so we can see what is happening? is there any console error?

Answer (score 0):

The "#course" syntax with a # is a syntax that I have not seen before. Try instead doing this:

```
<li *ngFor="let course of courses">
    {{course}}
</li>
```